# json_decode gives NULL

Tags: json

probably a duplicate question and i think i know the reson why it happens but cant solve it.

I got a json string i pass to php. In `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));` i get the right string with normal quots -> "" but when i do an `error_log()` on php side i get this:

```
 {&quot;obj&quot;:{&quot;1063&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:{&quot;article_id&quot;:&quot;1063&quot;,&quot;article_no_internal&quot;:&quot;400086&quot;,&quot;article_name_internal&quot;:&quot;Hotelbox Kurzurlaub&quot;},&quot;stk&quot;:&quot;100&quot;}}}
```

Its full of &quot and my `var_dump(json_decode($part_list_array, true));` returns a `NULL`

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your characters are being converted to HTML entities. Try this:

```
var_dump(json_decode(html_entity_decode($part_list_array), true));
```

Comment: that was it thanks. I saved the string in a hidden field and when i read it out probably thats when this happened.